# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_QuantLib'

Tags: python, quantlib

Can anyone help with this error?

I verified in Anaconda Navigator that quantlib-python (1.14) is installed.

---

```
import QuantLib as ql
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-11-b9e27c0bb1fd>", line 1, in <module>
    import QuantLib as ql

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from .QuantLib import *

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py", line 17, in <module>
    _QuantLib = swig_import_helper()

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\QuantLib\QuantLib.py", line 16, in swig_import_helper
    return importlib.import_module('_QuantLib')

  File "C:\Anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_QuantLib'
```

---

Thanks for the help,
Dave

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python 3.6: No module named \_QuantLib after installation of QuantLib and QuantLib-SWIG](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45539869/python-3-6-no-module-named-quantlib-after-installation-of-quantlib-and-quantli)

Answer (score 0):

Packages and modules in python can be imported when they appear in the `PYTHONPATH` environement variable or in the `sys.path` list.

On each `PYTHONPATH` expanding, will ends up in the `sys.path` list.

so make sure that, the instalation of your module was successeful and its path exist in the `sys.path` list. **how you check?** see below:

in comand line or in `script.py` type:

```
import sys
p=r'C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\QuantLib'
if p not in sys.path:
    print('QuantLib not in the sys path list!')
    sys.path.append(p)  #we add it to sys path now we can import it
```

its better to append new paths to the `PYTHONPATH` rather than editing the `sys.path`. Anywa, if the module you are trying to `import (QuantLib)` is a built in lib/module you should check if the pyhton installation was successful and the path environement variable edited correctly and has all paths that should be.